# Using Format with text file

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to write a variable (type double) value into a text file formatted to 3 decimal places, using `fileName.println(myVariable)`. Can I use a toString() and Format() function? I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: What language is that? Java?

Comment: in PHP you can use `printf()` to format the string the way you want. For instance:
`printf ('%.3f', $myVariable);`

Comment: It is a commercial process simulation tool that uses Java syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try the following code:

```
new DecimalFormat("###.###").format(myVariable)
```

This way you will get the exact format you desire.

Comment: Referring to the AnyLogic 7 Engine API Utilities class you can use a format(value), which uses a default AnyLogic formatter.